# Can I save videos, photos and documents in my Gmail Account?

Tags: gmail

I'm using a mobile device which is full of videos, photos and documents. So, the mobile device keeps on hanging. Those stuffs are important for me and don't want to lose them. I want to save them somewhere out of my phone. I don't have any other devices to save them in. So, I want to save them online storage which I'm unaware about. can I save videos, photos and documents in gmail draft or what step Is better to follow to upload my files there ?

one application named "Drive" is automatically is in my mobile device, (Which I didn't download) and It shows it has 15 GB. I doubt whether it is showing my phone storage. I don't know the matter is either.

I would like to keep them private, I don't like my stuffs being accessed by others.

Answer (score 2):

You can download the Google Photos app on your phone and create an account on photos.google.com and then configure your phone to automatically upload photos and videos to this account.

Comment: I'm talking about 'Gmail Account' and Drive.

Comment: what is total storage of gmail account all together?

Comment: Sorry about this, but when I answered your query, your question didnt include the "Drive" thing and just after I replied with the answer you had edited your answer.

But trust me, atleast for your photos and videos, google photos is a very reliable option and just a one time setting you need to do, after that it will automatically upload your newly captured photos and videos.

Comment: Google drive is limited to 15 GB while google photos give you unlimited free storage.

Comment: No problem for that. Google photos is also a service of gmail account or it's just an application? Next,  It only saves photos and videos, not documents. right ?

Comment: Next question ,"how much **mb** a video should be to save in  "Google photos" ?

Comment: Just like google drive which can be accessed through
1. website - http://drive.google.com/ 
2. mobile app

 Same way google photos can be accessed through https://photos.google.com/ and a mobile app for google photos is also available. 

At both the places you can use your google account to sign in as it is a service provided by google.

For more information, you can refer this link => https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6220791?hl=en-GB

Comment: For other file types use google drive instead. You have a link to access the google photos within the google drive website as well.

If you want all in one, then go for the one drive option but I don't have much idea about the overall storage and other information. When I was using windows phone I was using one drive. It was working perfectly fine for all types of documents.

Comment: Thank you I got it. I would use "Google photos" if I knew about one thing about video.I knew that “google photos” gives unlimited storage to upload photos and videos. How much ‘MB’ video is uploaded there ? Upto how much mb ? Sorry for being persistent.

Comment: An image within 75MB
A video within 10GB
I referred the following forum:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/photos/e2f1gmcbibU

Comment: But this website https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/photos/WINMZYNaz0I tells it's 1080p , what 1080p means?

Comment: how much mb it refers to ?

Comment: @yubrajsharma 1080p refers to the resolution, corresponding 1920x1080 pixels. It's what you would call Full HD.

Answer (score 1):

You can save them on "Google Drive" as well as "OneDrive" or other third parties storage.They will save your file securely..you can handle them by your email..

Comment: It means' drive' isn't an app but it's a service of Gmail account which allows to save files. Am I right ? can I save them in 'gmail draft' too ?